# how can i improve the implementation of my own hash map

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

For learning purposes, I'm writing my own implementation of the hash map. I'm using [separate chaining with list heads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_list_heads) as my theme.

This is what the structure would look like:

```
| 0   | ---> | 11 | ---> | 33 | ---> | -- | ---> | 121 | ---> | TAIL |
| 1   | ---> | 12 | ---> | 34 | ---> | -- | ---> | 122 | ---> | TAIL |
| -   |
| -   |
| -   |
| D-1 | ---> | -- | ---> | -- | ---> | -- | ---> | -- | ---> | TAIL |
```

It is an array of linked lists where,

**D** = size of the array,

| 11 | = element with key; 11 AND elements are inserted in sorted manner

Algorithm:

```
void Insert(key, value):
 int bucket = hash_fn(key); // key % D, for now
 // accessing this bucket or array-index in array is O(1)
 // insert in linked list at the right position
 LL[bucket]->insert(new object(key, value))

bool Lookup(key):
 int bucket = hash_fn(key); // key % D, for now
 // search for key in LL[bucket]
```

**Concern**: If a lot of elements get mapped to the same bucket, search will not be O(1), in fact, it may tend towards O(n).

How can I improve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. That's why it's crucial to prevent this from happening by using a good hash function that spreads items evenly over the buckets, and making sure you use enough buckets.

If you're willing to stray from the idea of a hash table with linked lists for the buckets, you can try putting some other data structure in the buckets - for example some sort of self-balancing tree, like a red-black or AVL one to get O(log(m)) behaviour, where m is the maximum number of entries per bucket. But that will not actually make you happy. Simply using a good hash function will.

Comment: You almost read my mind with the idea of self balancing tree to get that O(log(m) ) behaviour. However, I appreciate the wisdom of using a good hash function. Investigating in how hash tables work has been a great practical learning experience! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table):

> With a good hash function, the average lookup cost is nearly constant as the load factor increases from 0 up to 0.7(about 2/3 full) or so.[citation needed] Beyond that point, the probability of collisions and the cost of handling them increases.

So with a good enough hash function and a reasonably big hash table you should not concern about that.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is [Hashing with Chaining](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/an-introduction-to-hash-tables-with-chaining-r2066) which will use a linked list to help avoid collisions within a hash table.
This will allow your lookups remain quite constant, even with many elements mapped to the same hash bucket.

However, with a good enough hash function you would not need to worry about this unless you are expecting the hash table to get close to capacity.

[This Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) also contains some very good information about this technique.